# Local Administrators group in AD

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I have a bunch of PCs in my company AD and I want to give the person who most uses one given PC access to local Administrators group. I know, not the best idea but still I sometimes need my employees to install something themselves... What is the easiest way of doing this, preferably using Group Policy so it can be administered from one place?

What I have done to several PCs already is just manually add the domain user to the local Administrators group. That works but, eh, I'd like something a bit more global. I wass thinking that there is that "Managed by" property of a PC in ADUC so maybe use that or something. Whatever comes across your mind as a cool and pretty solution.

Comment: Group Policy Preferences.